# Bind records of two databases

Tags: c#, .net, sql, windows, postgresql

I have two Windows machines; each machine has a .NET C# application used to insert data to PostgreSQL data base tables.
Both machines have the same exact 4 tables which are: Binfiles , gendata, leave and training.

But each machine has different inserted records. I want to merge the inserted data to be in one machine only.
What is the best practice and easiest way to do that?

Comment: @AndrewBarber but.`.`.`points`?

Comment: I was joking because he was probably looking for something to edit to score imaginary internet points. But your comment is gone now, so I look silly

Comment: @AndrewBarber well I guess we solved it then. Now onto the question. Um Aan, do you mean that you have two different databases with the 4 same tables but different records and you want to combine them to one database?

Comment: @Scotch Yes dear as you said.

Comment: Maybe copy your tables from one machine to a csv then copy from that csv into your existing table?

Answer (score 1):

From one of your machines tables

```
 COPY binfiles TO '/tmp/binfiles.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
 COPY gendata TO '/tmp/gendata.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
 COPY leave TO '/tmp/leave.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
 COPY training TO '/tmp/gendata.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

then on your other machine you `copy from`

```
 COPY binfiles FROM '/tmp/binfiles.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

and so forth. or you could do it in SQL, but you would first need to have both sets of tables  `insert into newBin select * from oldbin`

Comment: I have tried it but it shows this error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "Date"
CONTEXT:  COPY binfiles, line 1, column Date: "Date"`

Comment: Was this from your COPY FROM statement? You shouldn't be getting `invalid input syntax` if your tables are identical

Comment: Yes it was COPY FROM, I think the problem is that `Date` is a keyword at the same time it is a name of one colum in the table. do u have idea?